# Google Play Store: "This app is incompatible with your device"

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

*Not a duplicate*

**Situation**:
My app is designed for smartphones and currently on the Google Play Store it displays that **my app is not compatible with my device and as well as no devices are supported**. I have uploaded my application's APK on Google Play Store **9 times** with different changes taking place at each time. I have gone through 15+ stack overflow questions and tried what different answers suggested and nothing helped or nothing worked.

**What I have tried and What I currently have**:
 1. Tried **Compatible screens** tag in AndroidManifest. 
 2. Tried **Support-screens** tag in AndroidManifest. 
 3. Tried having **both**. 
 4. **Removed some permissions** from AndroidManifest. 
 5. All the uses-feature currently have "**false**" as a requirement. 
 6. Had to put uses-feature "**android.hardware.telephony**" as Google Play Store was giving me the tip that my **APK is designed for tablets**.  
 7. Removed **unwanted and unnecessary files and code snippets** (Although I do have some Java files where I have made the whole code snippet of the class as a comment which I may require in future). 
 8. Placed different size **application logos in the mipmap folder** (Although I am not sure if this can really have an impact). 
 9. Currently, **I have only one layout folder** and have not designed different layouts or layout folders for different screen sizes so I am not sure whether this could have an effect.

**My Suspicions**: 
 1. Could be the **application theme**, since I have not defined an **apptheme** in the "**application**" tag in the AndroidManifest file. However, I have only defined the apptheme in the parent activity of the application. 
 2. Could be **not having different layouts** for different screen sizes. 
 3. Could be **one of the gradle build files** where I may need to change something, but, I do no know what it could be. 
 4. Could be something from AndroidManifest.

The following is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my package">

    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/applogo"
        android:label="my app name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true">

        <service
            android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="IALocationService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="My Key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_SECRET"
            android:value="My key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="my package" android:pathPrefix="/main"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".IPS"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BI"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
         </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SH"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Help"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following is my build.gradle(app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my package"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "9.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.indooratlas.android:indooratlas-android-sdk:2.0.0-beta@aar'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1'
}
```

I may even have tried more than what I have stated here.
If anybody knows what is wrong in the AndroidManifest file or what is wrong in my build.gradle file or what could be wrong based on my suspicions then I would be grateful. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue and we share the same list of things we've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove these all lines and try again.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

If you want to add tablet support then do your app design responsive and upload tablet screenshot to playstore. that's it.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I will try what you suggested and I have no intentions for making my app for both smartphones and tablets, so just sticking with smartphones at the moment. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using built in styles and themes, your app will naturally follow the latest look and feel of Android with each new release.

So in the application tag you need to add the theme, at least a built in one but without defining theme, there is no possible device that can run the 'themeless' app. So,

1) make sure you have under styles.xml something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

2) and in manifest for application tag,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

can you please check them

Comment: So I guess my suspicion was correct. And yes, I do have those lines of code in my styles.xml file. I will definitely try what you suggested and will let you know the outcome. Many thanks for this information.

Comment: Tried and did not work. Really do not know where is the problem after all these efforts.